# Plot a list of dictionaries using matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

```
List =
[{'Month': '1', 'Store': 'A', 'Sales': '100'},
 {'Month': '2', 'Store': 'A', 'Sales': '50'},
 {'Month': '3', 'Store': 'A', 'Sales': '200'},
 {'Month': '1', 'Store': 'B', 'Sales': '300'},
 {'Month': '2', 'Store': 'B', 'Sales': '200'},
 {'Month': '3', 'Store': 'B', 'Sales': '250'}]
```

I do know how to plot the basic line.

But how can I have a combined result with both data set?

Like this   [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5wbs.png)

Comment: Hint: Convert list to pandas dataframe, then use seaborn to plot the lines https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it. Place things in pandas simplify this - also, plot multiple line and then all will be shown on the same chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(your_data)
df[['Month', 'Sales']] = df[['Month', 'Sales']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
a = df[df.Store == 'A']
b = df[df.Store == 'B']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
a.plot('Month', 'Sales', ax=ax)
b.plot('Month', 'Sales', ax=ax)
ax.grid(True)
fig.set_facecolor('white')
```

[image]